# why is kvm pool so small

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh, virt-manager

I set up kvm on a fresh install ubuntu server 18.04 on a 1TB disk. There is nothing else on the disk. Whether I use virt-manager or virsh on cli to create a pool, I always get a pool of 3.75GB [screenshot of pool size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTD8r.png) The reason so little space is left in the pool is because I have an ubuntu server image there for the virtual server I am trying to create.

The default pool was created with 3.75GB and every new pool I create gets created with this size. I am trying to create a pool of 750GB for my virtual server, but cannot figure it out. I am never offered an option to specify pool size, only volume size, but that is restricted by pool size.I imagined that qemu would use all the free space on my disk by default for my pool. All the examples of setting up kvm virtual servers online have way bigger pools than me. What have I missed?

df -h

`Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              787M  1.2M  786M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/sda2                          976M  144M  765M  16% /boot
/dev/loop2                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
tmpfs                              787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/1000`

fdisk -l

`Disk /dev/loop0: 91.3 MiB, 95748096 bytes, 187008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`

`Disk /dev/loop2: 91.4 MiB, 95805440 bytes, 187120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`

`Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8E855DDE-1DBD-41AC-9F1A-C6D5097E0016`

`Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 1953521663 1951420416 930.5G Linux filesystem`

`Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x08b44167`

`Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes`

Comment: Can you add the "df -h" output (without double quotes)?

Comment: @eKKiM I added df and fdisk

Comment: Can you add the output of: "lvs", "vgs", "pvs".